# I have two lines of code, that i'm trying to get into one single line

Tags: python

I have a code that I should get into one line, but i just simply can't solve it

Here is the code:

```
import random

for i in range(10): print sorted(random.sample(range(1,40), 7))
```

I have tried different versions, like trying to put the import into the same line, without any results.

This is the website im using: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php

So I was wondering, how could I get it into a single line.

Comment: Hey, i was challenged to do it into a single line

Comment: do you mean import statement and for loop in one line?

Comment: Yeah, that's like a lottery generator, and it all should be in a one line.

Comment: i think it is already in one line. are you counting import statement as a line?

Comment: Yeah, it all should be in a single line (even the import). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple statements in one line makes code dirty and reduce code readability and not recommended. But it's possible.
Normally each statement is written on separate physical line in editor. However, statements in a block can be written in one line if they are separated by semicolon.[Refrence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-provide-multiple-statements-on-a-single-line-in-Python)

```
 import random ; ([(print (sorted(random.sample(range(1,40), 7))))for i in range(10)])
```

If putting two or more statements on a single line improves program clarity, then do so.When using more than one statement per line, organize the statement into columns. You can see [here](http://www.oualline.com/style/c04.html)

Comment: please do not use list comprehensions for side effects. This is not recommended, and considered a bad coding style.

Comment: This code is nearly perfect for what i need, it just has one problem. When i execute, the output is on a single line also. it should be in like a list style

Comment: print /n along with it

Comment: i don't think ; means one line....

Comment: Jainil, that code is good for me. but what point in the code i have to put the print /n

Comment: Hey, this is the perfect code! but just one problem, it doesn't run on 2.7.13. That's the version i have to use

Comment: It works on python 3.6. I checked on 2.7 this one:  print( [(sorted(random.sample(range(1,40), 7))) for i in range(10)])

Comment: Is this answer useful!?

Comment: Yes. This has resolved my whole problem.